# Which are good references for mobile webdev?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I would like to get a bit more into mobile webdev and searching for books or screencasts about this topic. Of course I found dozents, but I don't know which to choose.

Does it make sense to read books with a design part in it, although I won't ever make a design, but only implement them?

Any suggestions out there, are there some must have reads?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I am mainly searching for books, which cover themes like media-queries and so on. I have to put designs in to web pages and would like to improve my skills by making them mobile friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always found Smashing Magazine to be very helpful: http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/

If you prefer a book format, their Mobile Book is a collection of articles related to mobile design and development and is quite good: http://www.the-mobile-book.com/ It has a chapter on Responsive Design Patterns that you might find useful.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a sclabe template/framework or attempting to write it your self, DONT, It's a lot of work and it has been already written.

http://foundation.zurb.com/

It takes care of all your mobile need and scales to each framework. Its 100 % and just a template to start and take the hard work of your shoulder.

Comment: Of course I won't build a framework myself. But in cases I don't have the possibility to use one, because it doesn't fit the given design, which resources do you know to get better in mobile webdev?

Answer (score -1):

Well if you will be implementing the design into a mobile application then I wouldn't worry about learning the design bit of it. I would suggest you to have knowledge about the front end development.

If you will be developing mobile apps with html, js, css and any back-end programming language then I would suggest you to have a look at the Adobe Max 2013 screencasts in which they show loads of techniques and tools to programme mobile applications (mainly using PhoneGap).

The link to Adobe Max 2013: http://tv.adobe.com/show/max-2013/